# error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'require' in TypeScript compile process

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.8

I am compiling all TypeScript in my angular project but I am getting the well known error:

```
error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'require'.
```

However most people who have this issue are running into it because they have two **files** that cause the duplication error. In my case it is because of the word '*require*' being used twice in the **same** file.

```
/typings/globals/angular/index.d.ts(1707,9):
```

and

```
/typings/globals/angular/index.d.ts(1717,9):
```

[image]

it is the default angular typings definition file being pulled from the dt source.

I have TypeScript both locally and globally. I tried removing the local copy but that errors out. Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

and my typings.json:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20160627014139",
    "bootstrap": "registry:dt/bootstrap#3.3.5+20160619023404",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160620094458"
  }
}
```

and lastly my main index.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="globals/angular/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/bootstrap/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jquery/index.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't list `d.ts` files in the `files` section of your `tsconfig.json` file. That is the place that you list the files that you have written that need to be transpiled into javascript. The problem you're seeing is caused by the transpiler trying to convert your `typings/index.d.ts` file into javascript, which it should not do. The typings definitions are really only there so that your code editor can provide type hinting, warn you about errors, and do code completion.

Take a look at [this overview of the `tsconfig.json` file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).